# Microsoft Bot Framework ServiceUnavailable

Tags: c#, botframework

My bot was working well , but when i updated it and Uploaded it on azure , this error Service Unavailable appeared after clicking a Test on Test connection to your bot , My Azure account gave me free 30-days.
Below is is the LogCat:

```
ServiceUnavailable
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><!-- msdeploy: 5b0e43c4-568d-44fc-bac4-95edf41be79a --><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" > <head>     <title>Site Under Construction</title> </head> <body><!--                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Adding additional hidden content so that IE Friendly Errors don't prevent                                                   this message from displaying (note: it will show a 'friendly' 404                                                           error if the content isn't of a certain size).                                                                                                                                                                                                      --></body></html>
```

When i Re-Publish my Bot it also says:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.)   HuzFauKamz      0
```

What does this mean and what am i supposed to do ?

Comment: It's possible that you had connection issue, an intermittent server outage, or something temporary.  Have you tried re-publishing again?

Comment: Yah its true @EricDahlvang , it was a connection issue , when i re-published it again it worked